# Order of accuracy for non-smooth solutions and non-smooth local truncation errors

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics, regularity-theory-of-pdes, partial-differential-equations, truncation-error

I'm working with numerical methods for solving **PDEs** (Linear Advection/Euler equations with temporal and spatial discretisation) using **finite difference/finite volume methods**. In these simulations I have to deal with **non-smooth** solutions which I treat using **non-linear spatial discretisation schemes** such as **ENO/WENO** methods.

When one speaks about local and global truncation errors and their link to the global order of accuracy of the solution we usually suppose **"smooth"** solutions and linear spatial schemes (which don't depend on the solution). However, the definition of **"smooth"** becomes a bit cumbersome with space discretised solutions. How can one define the **"smoothness" of a discretised solution**? I suppose that one can apply the Fourier Transform to the discretised solution and observe that the contribution of each Fourier mode is not negligible (opposed to smooth solutions). However, I haven't found yet any formal definition of the smoothness of a discretised solutions, does anyone know if there exist a formal definition of the smoothness of discretised functions?

Moreover, for **non-smooth** solutions my spatial discretisation schemes become non-linear and therefore the local truncation error at each spatial discretised point of my domain becomes **"non-smooth"**, how can one then link this **local truncation error** to a general idea of **order of accuracy**?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A discretized solution is neither smooth nor discontinuous. The theoretical solution may be. Nevertheless, one can still introduce numerical smoothness indicators, see Ref. (1).

The definition of the order of accuracy assumes smooth solutions. Therefore, numerical estimation of the order of accuracy should be performed in a configuration where solutions are smooth. For many schemes, the order of accuracy (w.r.t. a given norm) drops in the vicinity of discontinuities. This can be analyzed theoretically, see Sec. 8.7 "Accuracy near discontinuities" of Ref. (2). Note that *the order of accuracy isn't everything*, as explained in (2).

(1) CW Shu: "High Order Weighted Essentially Nonoscillatory Schemes for Convection Dominated Problems", *SIAM Review* 51.1 (2009), 82-126. [doi:10.1137/070679065](https://www.doi.org/10.1137/070679065)

(2) RJ LeVeque: *Finite Volume Methods for Hyperbolic Problems*, Cambridge University Press, 2002. [doi:10.1017/CBO9780511791253](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511791253)

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, I already know by heart Shu's papers... I'll have a look at your your second reference. 

One more small question, in case that the analytical solution is smooth but the local truncation error is not smooth (for example due to a change in the numerical scheme used in different points of the discretised domain), does the same apply?

Thank you very much again